# What's the difference between Milestones and Snapshots?

Tags: coordinator, snapshot, milestones

As far as I understand Milestones are done by the Coordinator to verify transactions. What do Snapshots do? Do they serve as backup? Do they clean up dead tips? Who issues them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A milestone and a snapshot are two separate things.

Currently, the network has the coordinator set up to ensure that malicious attacks cannot occur. The specifics of what a milestone is are detailed in this answer: [What does the IOTA coordinator actually do?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-does-the-iota-coordinator-actually-do)

A snapshot is a separate technical feature of IOTA that essentially captures a snasphot of all balances at a specific time and prunes the history of transactions that led to that moment, in order to reduce the memory burden of nodes connected to the tangle.